# finding non repeating element.Code Does't print anything

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, unique

I want to add the unique element in array A to the list L.
This code doesn't print anything. Please tell me where i am going wrong.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Unique {
    public static void main(String[] args){


            List<Integer> L = new LinkedList<>();
            int[] A = {3,3,9,1,6,5,8,1,5,3};
            int[] B = {3,3,9,1,6,5,8,1,5,3};

            int count =0;
            //outer loop

            for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
            //inner loop
                for(int j=0;j<B.length;j++){
                    if(A[i]== B[j])count++;
                    }
                if(count==1) L.add(A[i]);
                }
            for(int i =0;i<L.size();i++){
                System.out.print(L.get(i)+" ");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can find other example at: http://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/distinct-elements/

Comment: Posting your homework assignments here for other people to solve them is not what this site is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line below inside your inner loop:

```
 int count = 0;
```

Your final code will be:

```
    // outer loop
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;

        // inner loop
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j])
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 1)
            L.add(A[i]);
    }
```

Output

```
9 6 8
```

Alternatively, you can write your code like this too:

```
    int count;

    // outer loop
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        count = 0;

        // inner loop
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j])
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 1)
            L.add(A[i]);
    }
```

Comment: that worked. thanks. can you explain why it doesn't work when its outside?i initialized it like any other variable.

Comment: Outside, the count variable will be initialized once. While inside it will be initialized at each "turn".